# How to silence a 5V electrical beeper/buzzer

Tags: piezo-buzzer

We have a simple circuit operated by 2 AAA batteries, it has a simple board inside with one of these 5V electrical beepers that makes sound every time it does something.

It looks exactly like the one in this page:
https://rcexplorer.se/product/5v-beeperbuzzer/

The problem is I want to silence it, maybe removing it would be enough but I don't want to do it without asking first because I don't know if it will break the device, maybe I have to replace it with something, or remove it leaving the circuit closed, I don't know what impact it can have.
Other solutions on how to make it more quiet even if it still beeps are also welcome, but I prefer complete silence.

Comment: Remove the conditions causing it to buzz, like “shut the door” ....

Comment: What does the simple circuit do?

Comment: squirt glue into the little hole for a 95% volume reduction. tape is good for 90%.

Comment: insert a toothpick into the hole and press gently. if it silences the buzzer then pack play-doh into the buzzer

Answer (score 4):

It'll be fine if you remove the buzzer and don't do anything else because the buzzer gets a constant voltage. Drawing no current will not change that constant voltage so the rest of the circuit should not be affected.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a typical a buzzer connection scheme then you can remove it. This will not disrupt the device. There may be a special case, but it looks doubtful.

You can add a sound absorbing material (foam rubber) to reduce the volume and not remove the buzzer. Try to attach it to the buzzer hole using two-sided adhesive tape.

The adhesive tape itself also significantly reduces the volume.